# c# gecko terminates immediately ( on some windows 10 machines)

Tags: c#, terminate, geckofx

I have a web + c# application all together. It perfectly works on two of my 3 windows 10 machines, however it doesnt work on windows 10 tablet.  I have  tried a different wrapper, it worked.

as soon as I click the exe,  it appears on the task manager, after  a few seconds it disappears.  Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Is the tablet a normal x86 machine? If so try comparing the output of Depend.exe on xul.dll , with the working machine, compared to the tablet.

Comment: @Tom  that is a tablet one  on z8350  processor. I will try and let you know